# Error While dynamically allocating memory for a two - D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am implementing a two dimensional array dynamic memory allocation . While compiling the program i got an error . The code is as follows :-

```
   # include<iostream>
   # include<stdio.h>
   # include<conio.h>
   # include<stdlib.h>
   # define COLS 5
   using namespace std;

   typedef int Rowarray[COLS];
   int main()
   {
      Rowarray *rptr;
      int nrows=3;
      int row,col;
      rptr=(int**)malloc(nrows * COLS * sizeof(int)) ; // Error Line
      for(row=0;row<nrows;row++)
      { static int i=0;
        for(col=0;col <COLS;col++,i++)
        {
          rptr[row][col]=i;
        }
      }  
      for(row=0;row<nrows;row++)
      { 
        for(col=0;col <COLS;col++)
        {
          cout << "\n" << rptr[row][col];
        }
      }     
     getch();  
     return 0;
   }
```

The error i am getting is `cannot convert int**' to`int (*)[5]' in assignment `

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` instead of `new`?

Comment: @camron i can use new but just want to learn how to typecast these in case of malloc

Comment: i guess `malloc(nrows * COLS * sizeof(int))` will return me just void* which i am trying to forcefully convert to int** as the left hand side of equal to operator has a int** type . Is that the error ?

Comment: use a simple one dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the cast (parentheses) to the left of malloc.  If that doesn't work replace them with `(Rowarray *)`.

Comment: Mine is an old compiler so it does not have latest ANSI feature , so i had to typecast that and it worked with your fix :)

Answer (score 3):

If you replace your ugly `malloc` with normal `new`

```
rptr= new Rowarray[nrows];
```

your program compiles and even runs. And don't forget to `delete [] rptr;`.

But why not use vectors?

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<std::vector<int> >rptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, and C/C++ doesn't let you cast to an array type anyway.

Your `Rowarray` should probably be a typedef of `int**`, so you can say:

```
rptr=(int**)malloc(nrows * COLS * sizeof(int)) ;
```

More generally, unless you have requirements imposed upon you because of homework or something, you're doing this is an overly hard way.  Instead of using `malloc` and raw pointers, you can easily create a dynamic 2d array with `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`

Comment: (int**) doesnot work here. I tried that :) . but i got it fixed through david answer

Comment: Yes it does.  You need to change your `typedef` statement to `typedef int** Rowarray;`

Comment: @Charles: An int** is a different type of 2D array than an array of arrays.  The former is an array of pointers, the latter is a big block of memory.